# What's the point of inserting images using CSS class:before/after and content attributes

Tags: html, css

Started working on a new web application recently and noticed they insert images into their pages by using [css pseudo-elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/). What is the point of this? Why not just use a normal `img` tag?

Comment: Less http requests to server = faster rendering?

Comment: We can't know why your co-workers do it but maybe you can ask them :-?

Comment: For the same reason that there are pseudo-elements with text as `content`: to not write the same markup for icons before or after specific elements multiple times. If you actually mean larger images that are part of the content, then it’s actually a strange thing. But we can’t know the minds of “them”.

Comment: @LeszekRepie Each image that is referenced with a URL needs to be fetched via an HTTP request or from cache, regardless of whether the URL is in CSS or in HTML.

Comment: @Xufox: right. But not url(data:image/gif;base64,..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Chopper Draw Lion4,

That's a great question which has several possible answers.

1. Its an older site and they were doing the old [image replacement technique](https://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)
   This was popular circa 2000 - 2010 when people believed that using text was more beneficial to SEM/SEO than using an image with an alt tag. It was "all the rage"
2. It could be useful in responsive markup. Depending on what kind of image/size. It may be that image only shows at certain response points. (yet one would still wonder why not hide them image rather than use a pseudo element)
3. Unskilled developer who just discovered pseudo-elements. This doesn't need much explanation.
4. The application may have been written in a way which did not give the ui developer access to the core html code which is injected.
   *I suspect this is the most likely reason. And the one I have come across most often.*

**Situation:** the ui developer needs to make something happen. But they have been forbidden from touching the actual coding.

**Example:**
*"Dear ui developer, please insert smiley faces or frowny faces depending on whether this is a positive comment or a negative one."*

```
<custom-directive data-grade="bad">{{Our Data is Great and You Stink}}<custom-directive>
<custom-directive data-grade="good">{{Your Data can Enjoy New Life}}<custom-directive>
```

***What would you do if this is all you were given and there were no interior elements to which you could insert the smiley/frowny face?***

Well, if it were me, I'd probably have to , at that point use a css pseudo element.

See this as an example to answer:
http://codepen.io/Acts7/pen/MJRrwa

Or this spiffy solution for a "star rating system"
https://codepen.io/Acts7/pen/BpEJRg

Hope this answers your question.